# How to get EC2 instance tags when pulling CloudWatch data?

Tags: monitoring, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

For monitoring purposes, we're pulling AWS/EC2 instances statistics data from CloudWatch and save it to InfluxDB.

We're using [Telegraf](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf) to do this.

However, when pulling the data from Cloudwatch, it doesn't contain the instance tags or env_variables, only the standard instance fields (instance_id, for example)

Is there a way to get this data when pulling the stats? Some other agent? A Lambda function?

Comment: Are you looking for an aws cli call to make? If so, `aws ecs describe-task-definition` may be what you want for getting environment variables. I can write up a bit more about it if that's correct.

Comment: I am using https://totalcloud.io . It pulls data from CloudWatch including tags and some more. Check if it helps.

Answer (score 2):

CloudWatch metrics contain "dimensions" that loosely match InfluxDB's concept of "tags". The list of dimensions available for EC2 metrics is available in the [AWS documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/ec2-metricscollected.html). Instances tags are not available and I'm not sure what you mean by `env_variables` but since all that is supported is

- AutoScalingGroupName
- ImageId
- InstanceId
- InstanceType

the answer is still going to be this is not possible.